# How to use JQuery selectors from dynamic Elements created from.Append function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this loop creating several divs with elements in it. I want to be able to attach a click event to every link with the "linky" class, and this link would read the contentID attribute.

I've searching forever, find cases to use selectors in dynamic created elements but just can't apply to my case. Any tips?

```
                    for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                        var htmlCode = "<a href='/Controller/Details/" + msg[i].ID + "' style = 'float: left;'><img class='packageImage' border='0' src='" + msg[i].Size0Path + "' /></a>";
                        htmlCode += "<span style='float: left;margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;'>" + "<b>" + msg[i].TheName + "</b><br>";


                        if (msg[i].IsPaused == true) {

                            htmlCode += "<a href='#bar' class=linky contentID='" + msg[i].ID + "'>Resume</a>";
                        } else {

                            htmlCode += "<a href='#bar' class=linky contentID='" + msg[i].ID + "'>Pause</a>";
                        }
                        htmlCode += "</span>";
                        htmlCode += "<div class='clear'></div>";
                        $("#divContent").append(htmlCode);
                    }
```

Given the answers, I'm trying to attach the event to class linky, but I just not sure where, see more details below, my instructions are creating the dynamic Elements from the result of ajax submit(post).

```
                    success: function (msg) {

                        $("body").on("click", "a.linky", function () {
                            alert($(this).attr("contentID"));
                        });



 for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                            var htmlCode = "<a href='/Controller/Details/" + msg[i].ID + "' style = 'float: left;'><img class='packageImage' border='0' src='" + msg[i].Size0Path + "' /></a>";
                            htmlCode += "<span style='float: left;margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;'>" + "<b>" + msg[i].TheName + "</b><br>";


                            if (msg[i].IsPaused == true) {

                                htmlCode += "<a href='#bar' class=linky contentID='" + msg[i].ID + "'>Resume</a>";
                            } else {

                                htmlCode += "<a href='#bar' class=linky contentID='" + msg[i].ID + "'>Pause</a>";
                            }
                            htmlCode += "</span>";
                            htmlCode += "<div class='clear'></div>";
                            $("#divContent").append(htmlCode);
                        }


 }
```

Comment: just a tip: for custom attributes use `data-*` this is a standard in `html5` and makes your html look clean you can call these variables with `.attr('data-*')` or `.data('*')`, for example `<a href='#bar' data-content-id="34">` you can call that with `.data('content-id')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the delegated form of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("body").on("click", "a.linky", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("contentID"));
});
```

You only need to do this once, before creating any dynamic content. It will attach an event handler to `<body>` that will respond to any of its descendants that satisfy the `a.linky` selector being clicked. It does not matter if these elements are already in the DOM at the moment you attach the handler or if they get added later.

Comment: thanks, I placed your code auside the function, before its declaration, inside the function, before/after the Elements creating, and it just don't work.

Comment: @EdwinSoho: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: the version I am using is 1.5.1

Comment: @EdwinSoho: `on` exists from 1.7.0 upwards. Either update your jQuery (recommended) or else use `$("body").delegate("a.linky", "click", function() { ... });`

Answer (score 3):

In this case you need to bind the event as soon as the element is created. But frequent binding and unbinding is a bad pattern.

So you are supposed to delegate the event i.e; attach the event to the parent container of these controls which listen to the events for its children and provide events to their children on which these are delegated..

Try this

```
$('body').on('click' , 'a.linky', function() {

      alert('Content id is : '+ $(this).attr('contentID'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just find the element after appending it attach the event handler there:

```
$("#divContent").append(htmlCode)
    .find('.linky')
    .click(function(){
        //your click handler
    });
```