# How can I refer by ID to the dynamic generated elements in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code in java script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#listOfCommercials').append('<div id="singleCommercial' + i + '"></div>');
        $('#singleCommercial' + i).html('...');

        i++; 
        alert(i);
    });

    $("#delete_row").click(function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#singleCommercial" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

and it generates extra fields every time when user presses the button. You can see it in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7yd5o63q/4/ I want to include the datetimepicker there and normally I would just write:

```
$('#datetimepicker').val(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+" "+time);
    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    });
```

but since I'm gonna generate a lot of fields:
    
then how can I refer to all of them and attach date time pickers to all of them (seems like the id cannot be the same for all of them)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need ids to set things up:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        var newCommercial = $("<div class='singleCommercial'><div class='form-group'>...<input class='datetimepicker'...</div>");
        newCommercial.appendTo($('#listOfCommercials'));

        newCommercial.find('.datetimepicker').val(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+" "+time).datetimepicker();
    });

    $("#delete_row").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.singleCommercial').remove();

    });
});
```

Comment: ok, but then when I have 5 datetimepicker fields and I hit 'save to database' how will I know which one is which one without ids?

Comment: Because each event is wrapped in a .singleCommercial you can process them like `$('.singleCommercial').each(function(){ var sc = $(this); var date = sc.find('datetimepicker').val(); ....});` or `var events = $('.singleComercial').map(function(){return { name: $("input[name='name']", this).val(), date: $('.datetimepicker', this).val(), };).get(); //then pass the array to your save function`

Comment: Thank you @bknights, just one more thing - could you help me and show me in some jsfiddle how exactly it could work? I'm a little bit lost with grabbing that data.. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how much detail you'd need. You should probably check the jQuery docs for how .find, $('selector', context) and .map work and see what you can figure out. How are you planning on sending your data to the server? If you are planning one big http POST then ids are not your issue - you'd need unique names. If you are planning on sending JSON (the modern option) then the techniques I outlined would work.

Comment: Unique names could be added as follows. Keep the 'i' as per your original example. The starting from my example before the datetimepicker is created do: `newCommercial.find('[name]').attr('name', function(idx, val){return val +'_'+i;});`  This will give each named element a unique name then your server code would have to group fields by suffix. Not as flexible as using JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes, instead of ids.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datatimepicker"...

$('.datetimepicker').val(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+" "+time);
    jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    });
```

Comment: hey, I tried that and it does work on the first datetimepicker element on my page, but when I generate more of them then it doesn't work there...

Comment: Does it work if you add the `$('.datetimepicker').val(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+" "+time);
    jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    });` stuff inside the click function for `addRow`?

Comment: You can also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657395/how-to-use-jquery-selectors-from-dynamic-elements-created-from-append-function

Comment: it worked when I added it like you suggested, now it works, but when I hit the 'addRow' button all date time values in previous datetimepickers are set to default value (and contains local time)... Maybe there should be a way of distinguishing them one from the other?

Comment: You could give them a dynamic id something like `id = "datetimepicker"+currentRowIndex`

Comment: Thanks for this clue! Could you show me some short example in my fiddle? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89945/discussion-between-anotherdev-and-randomuser1).